# Run PHP file from Bash

Tags: php, bash, sh, bin

I need to run a script that will execute a php file but I can't run the PHP file from Bash Script

Test.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
php /home/username/public_html/Test3/Test.php
```

Where is the error?

/var/log/cron :

```
Sep  7 22:56:01 srv CROND[4344]: (root) CMD (sh /home/Username/public_html/Test3/test.sh)
```

Test.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $date = date('h:i:s');
    $sql = "UPDATE deneme SET CRONTEST='".$date."' WHERE id=1";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->execute();

    echo $stmt->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: What is the output if you simply type `php -v` in bash?

Comment: Can you print the error you have in console?

Comment: Have you added `x` to file?

Comment: @MarcoSantarossa There are no errors

Comment: @u_mulder I dont understand, how?

Comment: If `php -v` does not work, then you have not installed PHP, or your user account cannot see it! And thats where I get lost in a unix environment

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I misunderstood the question, sorry. `PHP 5.6.14 (cli) (built: Jul  7 2016 20:57:16)`

Comment: @Saracoglu can you add the content of `Test.php` ?

Comment: First, ensure your command line launched PHP files have the right syntax at the top, then try the -f option

First 2 lines of CLI php scripts should be
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php


 php -f somefile.php

Comment: @MarcoSantarossa I updated my question, please check

Comment: @DuaneLortie http://pastebin.com/sFzSbF8T (?)

Answer (score 4):

Multiple ways to get this working. My first choice, call the PHP script directly from cron.
To do that, make sure your php script is executable (chmod 755)
Make sure the CLI php script starts with..

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
```

From a shell, type 'which php' and change the '/usr/bin...' line accordingly.
Once those steps are done, your cron entry might look like . . .

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/script.php
```

and again, make sure you point to php's actual location.
Tried explaining in comments, ran out of room :/

Answer (score 1):

I know it's old, but I just ran into this today. Whenever a Bash script does not execute a PHP script *(despite having correct permissions and the "php" command working on its own)*, I found using the full path to PHP resolves it. i.e.

```
#!/bin/bash

other code
...
/usr/bin/php /home/username/public_html/Test3/Test.php
```

You can use `which php` and `whereis php` to determine the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question this method:

```
#!/bin/bash

data=$(/usr/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/Test3/Test.php);
```

But I can't variables, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

data=$(/usr/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/Test3/Test.php name=Saracoglu);
```

Its not working. I'm searching..

Comment: Isn't this the same thing i have written in my answer?

Comment: @heemayl You don't have in answer `data=$( binPath -q path );`